# Determining the time that a response was cached in Apigee ResponseCache

Tags: caching, apigee

I'm trying to figure out when a response was stored in my ResponseCache. I see the following ResponseCache variables:

```
responsecache.<policy-name>.cachename
responsecache.<policy-name>.cachekey
responsecache.<policy-name>.cachehit
responsecache.<policy-name>.invalidentry
```

I don't see a variable for the time the response was cached. Is there such a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Apigee [ResponseCache policy](http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/reduce-latency-using-responsecache) automatically caches the entire response at the time the policy is encountered in the response flow. I don't believe there is any accessible variable that contains the time the response was placed in the cache. However, there is a way to accomplish this.

First, I'll summarize the ResponseCache flow. Say we have a ResponseCache policy RC1. You place it in both the request and response flow. Here is a diagram:

```
        -->[P]-->[P]-->[P]-->[RC1]-->[P*]-->[P*]-->[P*]-->
CLIENT                         v                            TARGET
        <--[P]<--[P]<--[P]<--[RC1]<--[P*]<--[P*]<--[P*]<--
```

When the flow reaches RC1 in the request flow, the cache key has already been built and the response cache is checked for a corresponding cached response.

In the case of a cache miss, all the policies (P, P*, and RC1) will be run. When RC1 is reached in the response flow, the entire response is stored in the cache and the flow continues.

When there is a cache hit, only the P and RC1 policies will be run. The P* policies will be skipped, and there will be no call to the target server.

Unlike the Cache policy, you don't get to define what goes in the cache for ResponseCache. It is the entire response. However, you can add your own data by adding it to the response.

In your case, right before the response RC1 policy is called in the response flow, add a header to the response with the current time (system.time). The response will be cached with your custom header in it. Then, after the response RC1 policy, extract and strip the time header from the response. Using the current system.time, you can also calculate how long the response has been in the cache.

Answer (score 0):

I like the answer provided by Mike. But trying to understand more on your use case - sounds like depending on the age of the cache entry you may not return it from cache. If that this the case, you can always specify the expiry setting such that older cache entries are automatically invalidated by Apigee Edge. No conditional programming required by you.

```
  <ExpirySettings>
    <TimeoutInSec>300</TimeoutInSec>
  </ExpirySettings>
```

Refer: http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/optimize-performance-using-cache

Comment: I'm using that already -- I just need to return how old the cache entry is in the response.